# mutool clean pdf output doesn't show German utf-8 characters (umlauts) and some special chars

Tags: pdf, unicode, conversion

- command: `mutool clean -d somepdf.pdf`
- piece of output:

> Die folgende Gegen`\374`berstellung von alter und neuer Logik hat
> selbstredend nichts zu tun mit der sp`\344`tmittelalterlichen
> Unterscheidung zwischen `\204`logica vetus \antiqua\ `\223` und `\204` logica
> nova \modernorum\ `\223`; diese bezog sich vielmehr auf den
> `\204` alten `\223` , d.h. schon vor dem 12. Jahrhundert bekannten Teil der
> aristotelischen Schriften zur Lgik Categoriae,De
> interpretatione\einerseits und den erst im 12. Jahrhundert
> widerentdeckten, also `\204` neuen `\223` aristotelischen Schriften zur
> Logik Analytica priora, Analytica posteriora, Topica, Sophistici
> elenchi andererseits.

- ToDo: Show output corresponding to German umlauts and special chars.

Comment: [I see](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/433354/andtoe) you haven't accepted any answers to any of your questions yet. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for what to do when you get an answer.

Comment: Can you show the output of `echo $LANG $LC_ALL`? And please take the time to look at the link provided by Ed Morton (or [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) if you prefer).